# name attribute of a control in asp.net takes id by default

Tags: html, asp.net, xml

why doesthe "name" attribute of the control in asp.net take the "id" value by default in asp.net ?

```
<%var ctrl =new  HtmlInputText();



 ctrl.ID = "ctrl_id";
 ctrl.Name="ctrl_name";

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
  HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

  ctrl.RenderControl(writer);%>
  <%=sb.ToString()%>
```

the above code renders a control , but the name attribute takes the value "ctrl_id" and not "ctrl_name"

Comment: Have you tried both:
cntrl.Attributes.Add("ID","cntrl_id");
cntrl.Attributes.Add("name","cntrl_name");

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ctrl.Attributes.Add("name","ctrl_name");
```

Comment: i tried !that din work , i tried somethin like  ctrl.Attributes.Add(ctrl.Name, "ctrl_name"); and its addin an extra attribute like   ctrl_id="ctrl_name", i dont understand how it takes the ctrl_id wen i say ctrl_name

Comment: use ctrl.Attributes.Add("name","ctrl_name");

Comment: yes yes i already tried it but the name still holds "ctrl_id"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an aside, but if you are adding controls dynamically to the page, it is usually better to add the control directly to another control's collection of child controls rather than Response.Write(ing) it out to the page.

```
var ctrl =new  HtmlInputText();
ctrl.ID = "ctrl_id";
ctrl.Name="ctrl_name";
//PlaceHolder1 has been defined in the ASPX page
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: thank you CHRIS! but the problem is not with addin the control , its with how i can override the value of "name" because it takes the value of id by default